# How to get the response by passing an UUID as parameter in gremlin query?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, janusgraph

I have a province id which is an UUID. I am able to get all the campaign sites without passing province id as a parameter.

```
    gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').in('partOf')..hasLabel('Province').has('type','city').in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').valueMap('provinceId')

==>{provinceId=[55bde744-307f-4767-8384-ed051bed414a]}
==>{provinceId=[1679cf43-f808-45b3-b132-244a03bc180b]}
==>{provinceId=[afe4ad5e-e911-4048-9364-63531657a5ee]}
==>{provinceId=[726dba5b-6d3c-45b1-8435-a726878e2304]}
==>{provinceId=[10721b98-a4e7-4672-9140-3b05c2c445d2]}
==>{provinceId=[fc61be4e-58ba-4874-b004-199a628bb1e3]}
==>{provinceId=[db43876d-267b-4063-bd51-e1ef47b77541]}
==>{provinceId=[49c68244-1ada-4131-b2dd-d8e0f6624379]}
==>{provinceId=[21bb9520-4d7d-4ffb-8458-abc1f79371ed]}
==>{provinceId=[cbcb774a-775b-42e3-92de-843bbf2141f6]}
==>{provinceId=[ed896879-3b94-491a-a759-680adcc22bbd]}
==>{provinceId=[cee46370-63b0-4cf3-898a-e38faef0edb9]}
==>{provinceId=[2850d6f1-a9fb-4e48-99d6-169c1b8570ca]}
==>{provinceId=[3c665c3a-4ddb-4909-a643-b24f27c2b71f]}
==>{provinceId=[4df1ceec-27f1-4f21-89cb-1d46b0332d21]}
==>{provinceId=[ef3094ea-390c-439d-8dfa-fdb1669fcaa2]}
==>{provinceId=[b00865c0-5482-48c4-86d5-34070a03dc12]}
==>{provinceId=[eb6eccd7-d842-4753-8b1e-3668a2cc9869]}
==>{provinceId=[184c1d55-eba0-41ac-9131-95ce5228c20d]}
==>{provinceId=[2c2c8a9e-f050-4921-a0c5-eba20e3bcc36]}
==>{provinceId=[83276863-b35b-4dde-8789-5aa90311a24b]}
==>{provinceId=[25623cb8-7564-4d8f-a276-ac40842209c7]}
==>{provinceId=[dcb9c708-8e23-4298-8369-0feb9e50c074]}
==>{provinceId=[06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d]}
```

But when I passed UUID as parameter to the query, then the result I got is nothing.

```
  g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','city').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('provinceId','06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d').valueMap(true)
```

But when I passed name as a parameter, then I am getting the correct result.

```
    gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('code','IN').in('partOf').hasLabel('Province').has('type','state').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','city').inE('partOf').outV().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('name','City Center').valueMap(true)
==>{label=Province, id=696332448, name=[City Center], location[POINT(78.448889 17.415)], type=[campaignSite], provinceId=[2c2c8a9ef050-4921-a0c5-eba20e3bcc36]}
```

I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that your problem is that you are storing your UUID as an actual `UUID` object but are querying by string:

```
has('provinceId','06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d')
```

If you store the "provinceId" as a `UUID` object then query it as such:

```
has('provinceId', UUID.fromString('06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d'))
```

I don't think JanusGraph does that type coercion for you in this case.

Comment: But when I tried this query g.V().hasLabel('Province').has('type','campaignSite').has('provinceId','06948da8-3cd3-4cd7-8d91-8aaa666e557d').valueMap().    I got the correct result

Comment: Thanks, UUID.fromString worked. But the above query worked, there should be difference. why it is working. Help me to clear this doubt.

Comment: I don't know. It should not work and your question indicates it did not, but your comment says it does so I'm confused as to what you say is happening and what is not. The confusion aside, the rule is simple: If you store your data as a `UUID` then query it as a `UUID` and not as a `String` - you can only use a `String` if the graph database you are using has the ability to coerce your `String` to a UUID.

Comment: Thank you. But when I am traversing through all the vertices then it is not working.But when I jump directly into the last vertex, string format is working. That's what is my doubt.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't follow that that means. perhaps you should update your question or ask a new one with a full Gremlin Console session that demonstrates what works and what does not.